# How to test Android 32 with Roboelectric

Tags: android, robolectric

My current Android application supports the following versions

android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.5"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

My unit tests are employing Roboelectric

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.7.3'
```

and I am configuring my junits as follows:-

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE, sdk = [O, O_MR1, P, Q, R, S, S_V2])
class MyUnitTest {

    @Test
    fun addition_isCorrect() {
        assertEquals(4, 2 + 2)
    }
}
```

however when I run my tests I receive the following exception for Android 32

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API level 32 is not available
    at org.robolectric.plugins.UnknownSdk.verifySupportedSdk(UnknownSdk.java:45)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:284)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getSandbox(RobolectricTestRunner.java:68)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:93)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:162)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

where does roboelectic document which versions of Android it supports?

e.g. the roboelectric road map for when 32 will be supported?

Comment: You're talking about something like [this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6920) ?

Comment: @Shark exactly that, that was raised in December, would have thought 32 would be supported by now

Comment: You know how those things go.... if you need something "for yesterday", check out the project, implement, make a PR, and help future yous. Or dont.  Either way, 4.7.3 doesn't have it.

Comment: @Shark  cannot argue with that, where do i find Whats new in 4.8-SNAPSHOT, as it looks like "At"Config has been removed

Comment: No idea, but robo was never very very friendly with backwards compatibility, which is exactly why people tend to stick with a version that works for them - because otherwise, updating leads to having to fix/redo all your tests and a bunch of other stuff... (which is unavoidable if a newer version fixes a bug you didn't know you had, but need fixed). Better to ask on their support forum/mailing list/git repo *shrug*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roboelectric 4.8 added support for api 32 at the end of April 2022:
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6920
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.8